# How to fixed react-native metro on DuplicateError?

Tags: react-native

Failed to construct transformer:  DuplicateError: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info
at setModule (E:\Project\ReactNative\mydemo\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:620:17)
at workerReply (E:\Project\ReactNative\mydemo\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:691:9)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async Promise.all (index 17) {
mockPath1: 'package.json',
mockPath2: 'template\package.json'

Comment: showing error on windows.